# Install4j 6.1: "Invalid mode" setting UNIX access mode

Tags: install4j

Since upgrading to from install4j `6.0.4` to `6.1` the `Set the UNIX access mode of files and directories` action fails with error message "Invalid mode"

```
[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.SetModeAction [ID 66248]: Invalid mode
        Execute action not successful after 0 ms
```

This was seen in Mac OS X.

The action is configured with a directory name, a file filter script which checks that the file name ends with`.sh`, the recursive checkbox is set, and the configured mode is `u+x`.

Has something changed about the action in the new release?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is indeed a regression in 6.1 where the backend has been changed to use the Java 7+ API and only octal modes are supported. This will be fixed in 6.1.1. Please contact support@ej-technologies.com to get the current build of 6.1.1 where chmod symbolic modes are supported again.

Comment: Thanks for the speedy response

Comment: Hi Ingo, I have similar problem on 6.1.1: `[ERROR] com.install4j.runtime.beans.actions.files.SetModeAction [ID 9553]: Mode +x cannot be parsed`. Mode `+x` is no longer supported? It works in 6.0.4.

Comment: If you change it to a+x, it will work, +x will be supported in 6.1.2.